# How to get all the types of a collection that inherit from a generic class?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, reflection

I have a collection ot types:

```
List<Type> types;
```

And I want to find out which of these types inherit from a concrete generic class without caring about T:

```
public class Generic<T>
```

I've tried with:

```
foreach(Type type in types)
{
    if (typeof(Generic<>).IsAssignableFrom(type))
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

But always returns false, probably due to generic element. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yeah, the downvote is odd

Comment: Can't you just iterate the `types` list and then add `elem.GetType().IsGenericType`?

Comment: @AndreiV: I want just the inheritors of the Generic<T> class, not any generic class.

Comment: Sorry, didn't fully understand. It's still too early, I guess...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AFAIK, no types report as inheriting from an **open** generic type: I suspect you'll have to loop manually:

```
static bool IsGeneric(Type type)
{
    while (type != null)
    {
        if (type.IsGenericType
            && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Generic<>))
        {
            return true;
        }
        type = type.BaseType;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then the sub-list is:

```
var sublist = types.FindAll(IsGeneric);
```

or:

```
var sublist = types.Where(IsGeneric).ToList();
```

or:

```
foreach(var type in types) {
    if(IsGeneric(type)) {
       // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should get first generic ancestor for the particular type in your list, and then compare generic type definition with `Generic<>`:

```
genericType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Generic<>)
```

Comment: @MarcGravell: yes, and "get first generic ancestor" assumes that. Otherwise, I can't imagine, how this fact can be established.

Comment: ah, true; of course, the first generic ancestor doesn't need to be the one you want ;p It could be `class Foo : Bar<string>`, `class Bar<T> : Generic<T>`